# Outlook is removing background color send from salesforce to outlook email

Tags: javascript, html, css, outlook

I am sending HTML from salesforce to outlook. It's normal html only. But when it's reaching outlook, the background color is not getting displayed.

Before sending:
[image]

After sending in outlook:
[image]

```html
<template>
  <div class="slds-p-around_x-large html-content" style=" padding: 20px 40px ;">
    <h1>GeeksforGeeks</h1>
    <h2>Placing div within a div</h2>
    <div style="background-color:rgb(195, 217, 237);width:73%;text-align:center;padding:7px;">
      <div style="background-color:#cc3353;width:50%;text-align:center;padding:2px;">
        <h3 style="font-size:2vw;">Example of div inside a div.</h3>
        <p style="font-size:2vw;">It has background color = #cc3353.</p>
        <p style="font-size:2vw;">This is some text in a div element.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <lightning-button
    variant="brand"
    label="Send Email"
    title="Primary action"
    onclick={handleSubmit}
    class="slds-m-left_x-small">
  </lightning-button>
</template>
```

Comment: Outlook doesn't support CSS background colors. When creating email templates, you need to write HTML like it's 1999. Modern CSS will almost never work consistently. Instead, opt for ancient HTML attributes like `bgcolor`. Use layout tables where necessary.  Campaign Monitor has a resource that will help with this: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: +1 to what Josh said. You're also using a template tag and that's not going to be supported by Outlook and many other email clients. Additionally, email clients don't support JavaScript nor web components: https://mailchimp.com/help/limitations-of-html-email